# SMS 2FA how to implement in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core-3.0

Is it possible to implement 2FA using SMS in a .net core 3 app?

Yes I've seen this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0 but the interface ISmsSender is no longer present in .NET Core 3.0 Identity nor .NET Core 2.0 for that matter.

So I don't see how this can still be implemented?

Cheers for any advice

Comment: Are you implementing your own 2FA solution for a custom auth pipeline? Or are you using an existing auth pipeline, like google or microsoft?

Comment: @scuba Steve I’m using the .net core 3 react spa template, which obviously has .net core identity 3 all set to go for using QR CODE 2FA

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. 

Why are you developing a custom sign in solution? You could use google/microsoft/etc. as your identity provider. In a lot of cases, this is preferable for clients, for example businesses that use Azure AD.

Answer (score -1):

You dont really need a library, most SMS gateways support simple REST calls. 
A library like Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client should be enough - and POST should consist of something like

> ```
> curl -X "POST" "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json" \   -d "from=AcmeInc" \   -d "text=A text message sent using the Nexmo SMS
> ```
>
> API" \   -d "to=$TO_NUMBER" \   -d "api_key=$NEXMO_API_KEY" \   -d
>   "api_secret=$NEXMO_API_SECRET"

nexmo has a .Net library as well https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/overview#sms-api-features